# ( IIS 8 ) FastCGI Rapid Failure Protection is disabled but still shuts down pool with FASTCGI_RAPID_FAILURE_PROTECTION events

Tags: php, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I am currently running a production Windows 2012 R2 enterprise server with IIS 8. I have began to have some trouble with daily reoccurring 500 errors which is directly related to the fast-cgi rapid failure protection "feature". The problem has been that while I have disabled this several months ago, I consistently have this problem which creates outages for about 8000 users randomly throughout the day for a brief moment. It's takes about 10-20 seconds and then it comes back. I understand that I should probably fix whatever is triggering rapid fail protection however, I would rather solve the immediate problem right now.

Is there any situation that would cause either a false flag or trigger rapid fail protection despite it being disabled? The following is a screenshot of this happening today. I apologize in advance for all of the trimming I had to do to the photo.

[image: IIS 8 continues to trigger FASTCGI_RAPID_FAILURE_PROTECTION even though it is disabled.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to fastcgi settings and look at 'rapid fails per minutes' there. what you are showing here is rapid fail protection on AppPool which will give you error 503 instead 500.

Comment: Thank you for this. I sincerely appreciate it. Worked like a charm.